# Subtraction of large numbers with exponents

Tags: exponentiation

Is there an easy way to break down the below formula?
And make it easy to calculate it mentally without the use of a calculator?

$108^2 - 92^2$

I know this is probably very basic, but I cant remember how.

Comment: The standard trick is $a^2-b^2=(a+b)(a-b)$

Comment: Yep, truly basic and simple. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint :

$$108^2-92^2=(108-92)(108+92)$$

Comment: You should get $3200$